# Queue width and height transitions in css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to queue CSS3 width and height transitions. When I click a div, its class is toggled by jquery to `active`, but I can't seem to get the width of the div to change first, and then the height.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#resize").click(function() {
    $("#resize").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
#resize.active {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s, 0.5s;
  transition-property: height, width;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s, 0.5s;
}

#resize {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, height;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s, 0.5s;
  transition-property: width, height;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0, 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resize">
  <h1>
    Stuff
  </h1>
</div>
```

[jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xmffL2mg/1/)

The desired order:

1. Click
2. Width increases in 0.5 s
3. Simultaneously wait 0.5 s
4. Height increases in 0.5 s

Right now, it all happens at the same time in the jFiddle. On my local machine it ignores the height transition (it just shoots to `300px` instead of easing, and then eases the width transition).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly,

The first duration value is affect on the first duration etc. So you need to change the `transition-duration` to `1s, 0.5s` instead of `0.5s, 0.5s`.

**Like this:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#resize").click(function() {
    $("#resize").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
#resize.active {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s, 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1s, 0.5s;
  transition-property: height, width;
  transition-duration: 1s, 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 1s, 0.5s;
}

#resize {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, height;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s, 1s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s, 1s;
  transition-property: width, height;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 1s;
  transition-delay: 0, 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resize">
  <h1>
    Stuff
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found out the automatic height drop was due to height:auto  as .active CSS property. This works well!